# Bind object properties to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This week in a conversation, I was told that the Pandas DataFrames could be used to bind object properties, but in a simple example I have not been able to achieve that:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

class MyObj:

    def __init__(self, x, y):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y


# create a list of objects
objects = list()
for i in range(1, 5):
    objects.append(MyObj(i, i**2))


# create the DataFrame and print it
data = list()
for obj in objects:
    data.append([obj.x, obj.y])

df = DataFrame(data=data, columns=['x', 'y'])
print('\nDataFrame content (prev)')
print(df)

# now change the df, and check the objects
df.values[3, 1] = 66
print('\nDataFrame content (post)')
print(df)


print('\nobjects content (post)')
for obj in objects:
    print([obj.x, obj.y])
```

The console printout is:

```
DataFrame content (prev)
   x   y
0  1   1
1  2   4
2  3   9
3  4  16

DataFrame content (post)
   x   y
0  1   1
1  2   4
2  3   9
3  4  66

objects content (post)
[1, 1]
[2, 4]
[3, 9]
[4, 16]
```

The objects content is not being binded.

Is it possible to bind object properties to a DataFrame?